# What should DataDog interval value be for custom count metric?

Tags: datadog

I've inherited an application that sends custom `count` metrics to DataDog via their HTTP API and we're getting some inconsistent readings in our dashboard reporting.

We are attempting to record a custom `count` metric every time a worker processes a single message off an SQS queue.

When we call the v1 **series endpoint** (`https://api.datadoghq.com/api/v1/series`)  we are passing an interval value of 0. Is this the right value to use?

I am new to DataDog so any help here would be appreciated.

I've had a look at the DataDog documentation but couldn't find any examples for this endpoint using the `count` type.

Comment: Are you talking about this endpoint: https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/metrics/#submit-metrics ?

Comment: @AasthaBist yes, but the v1 version. I've updated my post

Comment: What happened on simply setting `type="count"` in the `series`?